# How is a stolen aircraft returned to its owner?

Tags: general-aviation, security

Once the authorities figure out where a stolen GA aircraft is, do they get the owner to come take it back? do they fly it back to its home airport? How exactly does the owner get his hands back on it?

Comment: Simplest seems just to say "hey, your aircraft is standing there, come and pick".

Comment: Probably the same way a car is returned to its owner. Cops don’t drive it back to its home. It is impounded. If it had been used in a crime, it is kept as evidence until after all evidence is gathered, recorded, and filed. If they can not move the stolen item to an official impound yard or lot, it will be impounded in place. Locking it in a hangar and placing devices on the landing gear or propeller would deter a subsequent theft. They would then notify the owner or the insurance company (who is the new owner after paying the claim) to retrieve the item.

Comment: @DeanF. Please provide an answer in answers, not in comments.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast As Dean's comment is only a guess, it is suited for a comment. Answers should meet some quality standard (defined in the [help center](/help/how-to-answer)) and if Deans thinks its comment does not meet those quality standard, putting it in comment can help other writing good answer.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast - I have no idea how an airplane is returned. I do know how a car is returned in Texas. Even then, it may vary with police departments. A small-town country sheriff may spare the man-power to return the car in person to a resident who they know personally. But, larger departments will not spare the man-power or assume the liability. Chain of custody issues and all. I doubt they have a pilot on staff who would be willing to assume that responsibility, either. The OP can extrapolate an answer about airplane returns from there.

Answer (score 4):

If the owner retains ownership (rather than an insurance company who paid out a claim on the loss), it's up to the owner. The owner can either go pick it up if it is airworthy, or arrange for someone to ferry it back to the owner's home airport.